# Bot not responding

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to make my bot in discord on javascript, the bot goes online, shows in the console, but does not respond to messages

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

const TOKEN = "MY TOKEN"

const client = new Discord.Client({
     intents: [
        "Guilds",
        "GuildMessages"    
    ]

})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
})

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content.includes('ping'))
    if (userCooldown[message.author.id]) {
        userCooldown[message.author.id] = false;
        message.reply('Pong');
        setTimeout(() => {
            userCooldown[message.author.id] = true;
        }, 5000) // 5 sec
    }
})
client.login(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, there are a few issues at play here. Before I start, I should say that discord bots are moving away from reading message content and towards slash commands. If you have the opportunity to, please move towards slash commands. If you're looking for an up-to-date tutorial check out https://discordjs.guide.

With that being said, let me go through each issue one by one.

1. You're not asking for the `MessageContent` intent. You will not be able to check if the user's message contains ping

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
     intents: [
        "Guilds",
        "GuildMessages",
        "MessageContent"
    ]
})
```

2. I don't know if this is because this code has been shortened or not, but you're not defining `userCooldown` anywhere.

```js
const userCooldown = {}
```

3. `message` doesn't exist as an event anymore. Use `messageCreate` instead
4. Your cooldown logic doesn't really work. I would flip the boolean around

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if (message.content.includes('ping')) {
    if (!userCooldown[message.author.id]) {
      userCooldown[message.author.id] = true;
      message.reply('Pong');
      setTimeout(() => {
          userCooldown[message.author.id] = false;
      }, 5000) // 5 sec
    }
  }
})
```

5. You might have forgotten to enable this in the discord developer portal.
   [image]

The complete code I used to make it work is below. I wish you luck on your discord developer journey.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

const TOKEN = "TOKEN_HERE"

const client = new Discord.Client({
     intents: [
        "Guilds",
        "GuildMessages",
        "MessageContent"
    ]
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
})

const userCooldown = {}

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if (message.content.includes('ping')) {
    if (!userCooldown[message.author.id]) {
      userCooldown[message.author.id] = true;
      message.reply('Pong');
      setTimeout(() => {
          userCooldown[message.author.id] = false;
      }, 5000) // 5 sec
    }
  }
})
client.login(TOKEN)
```